# lzma command not found when executing shell script only under sudo

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I am building project source code in a SUSE server. 
The project build.sh called "lzma" command to compress kernel. 
The project build.sh need "sudo" to get access to some system command.
But I has tried to execute "sudo ./build.sh", and the shell always report error: "lzma: command not found."

I could execute "lzma" in shell with my user account. It works fine.
I also write a test shell script named "test.sh" which calls "lzma" command. 
I found that it fails with same error message if I excute "test.sh" with "sudo" .
But if I execute "test.sh" without "sudo", it works fine.
Why ?

Comment: `sudo` resets environment variables as a security measure. This means that your `PATH` can be disrupted.

Answer (score 2):

"Command not found" within `sudo` is almost invariably the result of an environment variable such as PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH (if what's missing is not the executable but a shared library it requires) or the like being altered.

You can pass working values through your environment variables through explicitly:

```
sudo PATH="$PATH" ./test.sh
```

Comment: Thanks and it works. Does it mean the sudo will find bin files in directories of PATH ?

Comment: The short answer to that is yes. (There's a longer answer that distinguishes between path lookups done by `sudo` itself and those done by other tools it invokes -- `sudo` actually does its own PATH lookup when first started because its configuration file whitelists binaries based on fully-qualified paths, but after a program has been started by `sudo`, it's then that program's own methods -- or C standard library calls such as `execvp` that it calls -- responsible for PATH lookups from that point forward).

Answer (score 1):

Sudo uses a different Path then your user account.

EDIT (see comments)

Try and execute:

```
type lzma
```

Say the output reads something like '/usr/bin/lzma', then just copy that output into your sudo command like (for example):

```
sudo /usr/bin/lzma
```

That should do the trick. You should also write the full path of lzma into your shell script if you are to run it as root.

EDIT 2:

Or, as Charles Duffy mentioned in his answer, you could leave all things as is and simply use `PATH="$PATH"` in your command if you are trying to execute your file as SUDO or as a different user.

Comment: `type lzma` is more comprehensive than `which lzma` -- the former tells you what the shell is actually executing; the latter only tells you what's first in the path. *Usually* those things are identical, but that's not always true.

Comment: That said, I'd tend to suggest -- if one *is* going to modify the script -- modifying it in a way that doesn't decrease its portability. Putting `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` at the top of a script won't prevent it from working on other systems where your `lzma` command *isn't* in `/usr/local/bin`, for example, whereas hardcoding `/usr/local/bin/lzma` means your script won't work anywhere else. (I realize that you're using `/usr/bin` in your example, but a default `PATH` without `/usr/bin` being configured in `/etc/sudoers` is nearly unheard of).

Comment: (...jumping back to my first comment: Consider if the user's dotfiles include `lzma() { /opt/something/bin/lzma "$@"; }; export -f lzma` -- the exported function will be available to scripts without sudo, but `which` won't be able to find it unless `/opt/something/bin` is in the PATH, whereas `type` will recognize it properly).